# Internal working of ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, concurrenthashmap

I was looking at source code of ConcurrentHashMap how how concurrent update has been handled. But looks like
its to complex to understand. Then i thought if i need to implement it my self how should i go about it. I came up
with simple algorithm. My question is is my algo on right path(i think yes) and
if i compare it with the jre 6 prescribed implementation where it lacks at high level?

Basically we have to do locking at individual bucket level(instead of whole HashMap)  so that concurrent update requires
locks only for entries which got to same bucket. Now bucket gets determined based on key's hashcode.similarly if we get
the lock based on hashcode, problem will be solved.  So two keys having different hashcode will go to the separate buckets
and hence we can use synchronize block on interned hashcode value(purpose of using interned value is so that lock is acquired on same object which lies under same bucket). In this case synchronization will happen on different interned
hashcode strings. so, concurrent hashcode can happen.

So two keys having equal hashcode will go to the same buckets .So, we can use synchronize block on interned hashcode value and
avoid concurrent update

here is my proposed put method

```
     public V put(K key, V value) {

     int hashCode = geKeyHashcode();
     String stringHashcode = hashCode + "";

     synchronized (str.intern()) { // line A

     // proceed for put operation
     }

     }
```

Now at line A, we can stop concurrent updates lying under same bucket/segment, though proceed for lying under separate bucket/segment

I am sure it can be improved a lot but main point it can be achieved be simple algorithm also. Is n't it?

**UPDATE :-** If someone can forward/point to the resource which explains java 6 prescribed ConcurrentHashMap in easier manner it would be great(I tried Googling but couldn't spot which explains how put method is implementated like usage of unsafe etc)

Comment: Please note that the implementation has radically changed between Java 7 & Java 8. I would pick one to understand & start from that. The archives of the concurrency-interest mailing list may also be of interest.

Comment: Imagine you have 200 instances of your map implementation. Each time you put a value in one of the maps, it will lock the buckets having the same hashCode in all the other 199 maps. That's already an enormous flaw of your simple algorithm. The engineers behind ConcurrentHashMap know what they're doing.

Comment: @JB Nizet. You are right here. Thats what i was looking for. Also i am not saying Engineers does not know what they are doing. I myself knew there must have been some serious flaw but i just wanted to get on it

Comment: In addition to what *JB Nizet* said, locking a hashcode doesn't lock a bucket: you can have multiple entries in the same bucket with different hashcodes. A better approach is to create a `ReadWriteLock` for each bucket and use it. This, of course, adds a lot of overhead, particularly for large maps, so the JDK implementation (at least as-of 1.6) used a reduced number of locks, and applied them to multiple buckets.

Comment: @ kdgregory i think different hashcode will ensure entry lie in different bucket in most of the cases.

Comment: And is "most of the cases" really good enough? Is it really OK if you have a concurrency failure 1% of the time? Or 0.001%?